# Haskell: Can this code be optimized?

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have the following code. I want to know whether there is any way it can be optimized so that it runs faster.

I wanted to solve it using a `SegmentTree` but I am not well versed with Haskell, which is why I took the following list (non-tree) approach.

```
-- Program execution begins here
main :: IO()
main = do
  _ <- getLine
  arr <- map (read :: String -> Integer) . words <$> getLine
  queryList <- readData
  let queries = map (read :: String -> Integer) queryList
  putStrLn ""
  mapM_ print $ compute queries arr  

-- Construct a sublist
sublist :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
sublist start end list = take (fromInteger end - fromInteger start) . drop (fromInteger start) $ list

-- Calculate the resulting list
compute :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
compute [_] [_] = []
compute [_] [] = []
compute [_] (_:_) = []
compute [] (_:_) = []
compute [] [] = []
compute (x1:x2:xs) list = result : compute xs list where
  result = frequency $ sublist x1 x2 list 

-- Read query list, end at terminating condition
readData :: IO [String]
readData = do
  x <- getLine
  if x == "0"
    then return []
    else do xs <- readData
            return (words x ++ xs)

-- Return count of the most frequent element in a list
frequency :: [Integer] -> Integer
frequency list = toInteger (snd $ maximumBy (compare `on` snd) counts) where
  counts = nub [(element, count) | element <- list, let count = length (filter (element ==) list)]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Precompute the frequencies of each prefix of the list. To compute the frequencies of a sublist, subtract the frequencies of the two prefixes ending at the two ends of the sublist. This will reduce the cost of each query from O(n^2) to O(n). To compute frequencies, use a counting sort. This will reduce the cost of the precomputation from O(n^2) to O(n log n).

Comment: Can you explain with code please? Thanks

Comment: @ZubinKadva You can convince me that it's worth my time by spending a little time yourself to try to figure it out (perhaps Googling terms you don't know), then cooking up a question that identifies where you got stuck in that process. You might also like the venerable [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), especially [If you don't understand...](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#lesser) and [Be explicit about your question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#explicit).